# (UIButton) -> 0' does not have a member named 'setTitleColor'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to modify the colour of a UIButton in Swift using the code below:

```
struct ColorWheel {
    let colorsArray = [
        UIColor(red: 90/255.0, green: 187/255.0, blue: 181/255.0, alpha: 1.0), //teal color
        UIColor(red: 222/255.0, green: 171/255.0, blue: 66/255.0, alpha: 1.0), //yellow color
        UIColor(red: 223/255.0, green: 86/255.0, blue: 94/255.0, alpha: 1.0), //red color
        UIColor(red: 239/255.0, green: 130/255.0, blue: 100/255.0, alpha: 1.0), //orange color
        UIColor(red: 77/255.0, green: 75/255.0, blue: 82/255.0, alpha: 1.0), //dark color
        UIColor(red: 105/255.0, green: 94/255.0, blue: 133/255.0, alpha: 1.0), //purple color
        UIColor(red: 85/255.0, green: 176/255.0, blue: 112/255.0, alpha: 1.0), //green color
    ]

    func randomColor() -> UIColor {
        var unsignedArrayCount = UInt32(colorsArray.count)
        var unsignedRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(unsignedArrayCount)
        var randomNumber = Int(unsignedRandomNumber)

        return colorsArray[randomNumber]
    }
}
var colorWheel = ColorWheel()
var randomColor = colorWheel.randomColor()
view.backgroundColor = randomColor
myButton.setTitleColor(randomColor, forState: .Normal)
```

This code will work perfectly when changing the background colour, but when I try to use the `setTitleColor` method, I get the following error:

`(UIButton) -> 0' does not have a member named 'setTitleColor'`

Comment: How did you declare myButton ?

Comment: In my app that code works just fine.

Comment: Your code works for me. Can you show us the context this code is in? There must be something else going on.

Comment: Also, which version of Xcode are you running? With Swift that can be a pretty important factor.